# ORDER query BY two variables : sum() and date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

My website displays a list of images (medias) where people can upvote and downvote them. I would like to be able to list the images by the most upvoted **and** recent.

here is my 2 tables :

medias

```
+----+-------+-----------+---------------------+
| id | name  |    url    |        date         |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 | koala | koala.jpg | 2017-10-03 09:27:19 |
|  2 | ...   | ...       | 2017-10-02 09:27:01 |
|  3 | ...   | ...       | 2017-10-01 09:25:23 |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------------+
```

votes

```
+----+----------+-------+---------------------+
| id | media_id | value |        date         |
+----+----------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |        1 |     1 | 2017-10-03 09:27:19 |
|  2 |        1 |    -1 | 2017-10-03 03:27:19 |
|  3 |        2 |     1 | 2017-10-03 02:27:19 |
+----+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

So far I'm able to list the medias by the most upvoted but I can't find a way to join the `medias` table and use `medias.date` for ordering by.

```
$q = $db->query('SELECT media_id,SUM(value) AS trend FROM votes GROUP BY media_id ORDER BY trend DESC');

while($data = $q->fetch())
{
  echo $data['media_id'].'<br>';
}
```

any help?

edit: I would like to order my medias by medias.date in addition to the first query.

Comment: Have you tried joining the tables?

Comment: By which date do you want to order? you're grouping .. you have more than 1 date for each group .

Comment: @sagi from the context I'm assuming it's the medias date otherwise there'd be no need to join.

Comment: You're looking at the `votes` table. The `media` table date is the one OP *probably* wants. Again I have no idea. OP seems to have disappeared.

Comment: I would like to order my medias by medias.date in addition to the first query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the tables. Use the query:

```
SELECT m.id,SUM(v.value) AS trend 
FROM media m 
  JOIN votes v 
    ON m.id=v.media_id 
GROUP BY m.id 
ORDER BY trend DESC, m.date DESC
```

Check the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da4455/1/0

Answer (score 2):

Just `JOIN` both tables.

Example:

```
SELECT rating.trend, medias.date, medias.id
FROM (SELECT media_id, SUM(value) AS trend FROM votes GROUP BY media_id) AS rating
INNER JOIN medias ON medias.id = rating.media_id
ORDER BY rating.trend DESC, medias.date DESC
```

Also you can add the `name` and `url` columns from the `medias` table.